# How to show error while typing or setting data in android studio with Annotation

Tags: java, android, sdk, annotations

I am working on a sdk project. So I have a bean class say NetworkRequest. There are two variable. 1. method 2. entity

```
class NetworkRequest{
int method=0;
String entity;

//Setter and getter
}
```

My question is if i am setting 1 to setter method, for networkRequestObject will check  is entity is null and if so show error to set entity in IDE.

```
networkRequest.setMethod(1);// show error in ide
```

Is this only a mith or reality?
please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood the question, you want to handle method argument properly which could be NULL.

As of now, until Java 8 annotations to check for NULL is not supported. 
But Annotations support [pluggable type systems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html).

For example, you can explore [Checker Framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/) to check possibility of NULL of method argument.
In the following code sample, it will show compilation error, if method argument `nbl` is handled properly. Here, `nbl` could be NULL and if not handled properly it may throw NPE.

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

class A {
void foo(Object nn, @Nullable Object nbl) {
    nn.toString(); // OK

    nbl.toString(); // Error
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     A obj = new A();
     obj.foo(new Object(), new Object());
 }
}
```

After proper handling:

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

class A {
 void foo(Object nn, @Nullable Object nbl) {
  nn.toString(); // OK

  if(nbl != null)
   nbl.toString(); // No Error
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  A obj = new A();
  obj.foo(new Object(), new Object());
 }
}
```

For using this framework with Android, you can refer [here](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#android-gradle).

Comment: Is checker Framework is library?. Can I include it in an android program.  Is there is not a Annotation for these type of need?

Comment: Yes its a library. Upto Java 8, Java doesn't have in-built type checking annotations. Updated the answer for usage of this framework with Android.